# How do I call this async function from Bittrex?

Tags: python-3.x, async-await

I had a script that I used for checking my balances in Bittrex and now I'm trying to upgrade to the WebSocket API but I'm having a hard time since there's a lot of concepts I don't understand. This is function I'm trying to call:

```
from signalr_aio import Connection
from base64 import b64decode
from zlib import decompress, MAX_WBITS
import hashlib
import hmac
import json

async def create_signature(api_secret, challenge):
    api_sign = hmac.new(api_secret.encode(), challenge.encode(), 
hashlib.sha512).hexdigest()
    return api_sign
```

From there I need to pass `api_sign` to to another function. I've tried playing around with it but I can't even get `print(create_signature(api_secret, challenge))` to work. The asyncio module isn't even imported either so I can't use the information I found on how async works, and I'm assuming it's not necessary to import it.

When I try calling it the way I would a regular function I get that the coroutine was never awaited

Comment: Take a look at the example coroutines from the documentation: https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#example-hello-world-coroutine

Comment: `async def` creates a coroutine function that when called returns a coroutine object but **does not start its code running**. The docs [Tasks and coroutines](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html) advise: "There are two basic ways to start it running: call `await coroutine` or `yield from coroutine` from another coroutine (assuming the other coroutine is already running!), or schedule its execution using the `ensure_future()` function or the `AbstractEventLoop.create_task()` method."

Answer (score 0):

I am the author of the example you are using. If you can't figure out how the authentication is done from the example or if its beyond your current understanding, then I suggest to use either:

Async: https://github.com/slazarov/python-bittrex-websocket-aio

Non-async: https://github.com/slazarov/python-bittrex-websocket

**I am the author of both libraries**

Comment: Yea i ended up using the non-async one instead haha. I'm having a much easier time with it, but I hope one day I can come back to this and complete it successfully